# Can one type of bacteria cause several diseases?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, pathology, health, safety

If yes.
Does it change its shape in every disease, or does it remain in the same shape and cause several diseases?

Comment: If you are describing a taxon of bacterium, then it is definite that a bacterial taxon is capable of this, depending on your definition of disease. A pathogenic bacterium could infect two different host species (Mycobacterium sp. in fish and humans). Additionally, a particular pathogenesis may be determined by the site of the bacterial infection. For example, Staphylococcus aureus is often associated with cutaneous diseases (Staph infection) like dermatitis. It may also induce pneumonia and endocarditis, still retaining the same shape - a coccoid-type - and still cause several diseases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one type of bacteria can cause multiple diseases.  For example:

*"Rheumatic fever is caused by group A Streptococcus. This bacterium causes strep throat or, in a small percentage of people, scarlet fever. It’s an inflammatory disorder."* [https://www.healthline.com/health/rheumatic-fever#causes].

The difference is in how the individual's immune system responds to the infection (and how the infection is treated).  Everyone responds a bit differently to the same infection.

Comment: "The difference is in how the individual's immune system responds to the infection (and how the infection is treated). Everyone responds a bit differently to the same infection." Can you support this with a reliable source?

Comment: I can give you some good examples:

Comment: Valley fever (a fungus disease that affects the lungs) is no more serious than a minor cold to some people, but kills some people.  Although malaria is a multicellular parasite, the fact that people with sickle-cell anemia (which is due to a particular genetic variation) are more resistant than other people shows that a victim's genetics can affect how a disease affects the victim.  Flu often affects certain age groups more severely than other age groups.

Comment: And, a classical example is the results of Europeans' introduction of measles to the native Americans: a disease that was a minor discomfort to the Europeans was deadly to the native Americans.

Comment: The example of group A Streptococcus causing strep throat sometimes, rheumatic fever sometimes, and scarlet fever sometimes is really perfect: the same bacterium affects different people differently.

Comment: Your opinions aren't what I mean by a reliable source, unless you can link to research articles you've written and which have been accepted by peer-reviewed journals. Or if you wrote a chapter on immunology in a textbook, etc.

Comment: Do you need research articles, or would you accept, e.g., a statement by the Mayo Clinic? [https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/rheumatic-fever/symptoms-causes/syc-20354588]

Comment: Or perhaps The Merck Manual: [https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/infectious-diseases/gram-positive-cocci/streptococcal-infections].  A good counter-argument would be to assert that scarlet fever, rheumatic fever, strep throat, etc., are all the same disease because they are caused by the same Streptococcus pyogenes bacterium; but per [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1299105/] which points out the vagueness of the definition of "disease", that would just be an opinion. The Merck Manual calls them different diseases.